# Properly define font family for Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got the following graph, and I encouter difficulties to properly understand how the font are managed in Latex.

<[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{tgadventor}


\usepackage{adjustbox}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{245,128,37}
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{0,0,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamilly}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=0.75}}

\tikzset{fct/.style={thick, opacity=0.8, smooth, samples=200}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width={15cm},totalheight={15cm},keepaspectratio}


\begin{tikzpicture} [pictparam]

%%%% FUNCTIONS %%%%
% Ceci permet de déterminer les limites du repère
\newcommand{\xlab}{X}
\newcommand{\xmin}{-7}
\newcommand{\xmax}{3}

\newcommand{\ylab}{Y}
\newcommand{\ymin}{-3}
\newcommand{\ymax}{7}

\newcommand{\graduation}{5}   %graduation du tableau

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Grille à placer en premier
\draw[gray, ultra thin] (\xmin,\ymin) grid (\xmax,\ymax);

% Axes à placer sur la grille
\draw[->] (\xmin-0.2,0) -- (\xmax+0.4,0);
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-0.2) -- (0,\ymax+0.4);
\draw (\xmax+0.8,0) node [below] {\footnotesize \xlab};
\draw (0,\ymax+0.8) node [left] {\footnotesize \ylab};

% Traits et valeurs sur les axes
\draw[color=black] (0,0) node[below left] {\footnotesize $0$}; % dot(0,0)

\foreach \x in {\xmin,...,-1}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    }
\foreach \x in {1,...,\xmax}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    }
\foreach \y in {1,...,\ymax}
    {   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (0,0) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    }
\foreach \y in {\ymin,...,-1}
    {   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (0,0) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    }

% Limitation des tracés dans la zone délimitée par la grille
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);

% Tracés de fonctions
%% Question 2
% d'abord l'orange
\draw[orange, fct, domain=\xmin-1:\xmax] plot (\x+1,{(\x^(1/3))+3});
\node[orange] (h) at (0.6,1.6) {$h(x)$};
%\draw[orange] (0.3,1.6) node {$h$};;
 puis le bleu
\draw[bleu, fct, domain=\xmin-1:\xmax] plot (\x,{-(\x/7)^2 + (10/3)});
\node[bleu] (i) at (-4.4,2.4) {$i(x)$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

I would like to change the default font familly from sansmath to tgadventor. 
I observed that loading the package "tgadventor" before the package "sansmath", applied the font change. But i'm unable to properly understand why.

I observed that I need the package "sansmath" to change the font familly, but reading the package manual didn't give me any answer.

And my biggest problem: when I'm converting the pdf to a svg picture, i lose the font family change.
I don't know why, but I think the problem come from the way i'm changing the font familly

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. We haven't file `parameters.tex` ...

Comment: I edit the post and  change the code to make it compilable. my bad! I'm a bit tired.

Comment: I’m surprised `\sffamilly` compiles.

Comment: I don't know, the personne who asked me to work in LaTex , declare it always like that. `font={\sansmath\sffamily}`. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s check the documentation. [The `sansmath` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sansmath/sansmath.pdf) says:

> Within the scope of the `\sansmath` declaration, maths characters will be taken from the text sans-serif family as much as possible. The actual sans fonts are `OT1` encodings of those indicated by the meaning of `\sfdefault` *WHEN THE PACKAGE WAS LOADED*, not the meaning at each maths environment!

So you have to change the default sans-serif font, then load `sansmath`.  After that, you can change your fonts to whatever you want, and `\sansmath` will still use the one you selected before.

For completeness, you have a few alternatives.  The `isomath` package also gives you selectable sans-serif math alphabets. If you are using XeLaTeX, you could try `mathspec`. Finally, in `unicode-math`, you could select

```
\setmathfont[version=sans, Scale = MatchLowercase]{Fira Math}

\newcommand\sansmath{\mathversion{sans}}
```

Unfortunately, as of 2020, `unicode-math` does not let you combine the `range=` and `version=` options of `\setmathfont`.

### Fixing the MWE

To get this working in `pdflatex`, make the following three changes.  The `sansmath` package needs OT1 encoding for Greek uppercase letters, so load it in addition to T1.

As mentioned above, `sansmath` uses whatever sans-serif font was the default when it was loaded, so load `tgadventor` first.

Finally, there is one typo. `\sffamilly` should be `\sffamily`.

That gives you the following working MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage{adjustbox}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{245,128,37}
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{0,0,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=0.75}}

\tikzset{fct/.style={thick, opacity=0.8, smooth, samples=200}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width={15cm},totalheight={15cm},keepaspectratio}


\begin{tikzpicture} [pictparam]

%%%% FUNCTIONS %%%%
% Ceci permet de déterminer les limites du repère
\newcommand{\xlab}{X}
\newcommand{\xmin}{-7}
\newcommand{\xmax}{3}

\newcommand{\ylab}{Y}
\newcommand{\ymin}{-3}
\newcommand{\ymax}{7}

\newcommand{\graduation}{5}   %graduation du tableau

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Grille à placer en premier
\draw[gray, ultra thin] (\xmin,\ymin) grid (\xmax,\ymax);

% Axes à placer sur la grille
\draw[->] (\xmin-0.2,0) -- (\xmax+0.4,0);
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-0.2) -- (0,\ymax+0.4);
\draw (\xmax+0.8,0) node [below] {\footnotesize \xlab};
\draw (0,\ymax+0.8) node [left] {\footnotesize \ylab};

% Traits et valeurs sur les axes
\draw[color=black] (0,0) node[below left] {\footnotesize $0$}; % dot(0,0)

\foreach \x in {\xmin,...,-1}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    }
\foreach \x in {1,...,\xmax}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    }
\foreach \y in {1,...,\ymax}
    {   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (0,0) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    }
\foreach \y in {\ymin,...,-1}
    {   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (0,0) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    }

% Limitation des tracés dans la zone délimitée par la grille
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);

% Tracés de fonctions
%% Question 2
% d'abord l'orange
\draw[orange, fct, domain=\xmin-1:\xmax] plot (\x+1,{(\x^(1/3))+3});
\node[orange] (h) at (0.6,1.6) {$h(x)$};
%\draw[orange] (0.3,1.6) node {$h$};;
 puis le bleu
\draw[bleu, fct, domain=\xmin-1:\xmax] plot (\x,{-(\x/7)^2 + (10/3)});
\node[bleu] (i) at (-4.4,2.4) {$i(x)$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can instead do this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale = 1.0]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[version=sans]{Fira Math}

\newcommand\sansmath{\mathversion{sans}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{245,128,37}
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{0,0,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=0.75}}

\tikzset{fct/.style={thick, opacity=0.8, smooth, samples=200}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width={15cm},totalheight={15cm},keepaspectratio}


\begin{tikzpicture} [pictparam]

%%%% FUNCTIONS %%%%
% Ceci permet de déterminer les limites du repère
\newcommand{\xlab}{X}
\newcommand{\xmin}{-7}
\newcommand{\xmax}{3}

\newcommand{\ylab}{Y}
\newcommand{\ymin}{-3}
\newcommand{\ymax}{7}

\newcommand{\graduation}{5}   %graduation du tableau

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Data Table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Grille à placer en premier
\draw[gray, ultra thin] (\xmin,\ymin) grid (\xmax,\ymax);

% Axes à placer sur la grille
\draw[->] (\xmin-0.2,0) -- (\xmax+0.4,0);
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-0.2) -- (0,\ymax+0.4);
\draw (\xmax+0.8,0) node [below] {\footnotesize \xlab};
\draw (0,\ymax+0.8) node [left] {\footnotesize \ylab};

% Traits et valeurs sur les axes
\draw[color=black] (0,0) node[below left] {\footnotesize $0$}; % dot(0,0)

\foreach \x in {\xmin,...,-1}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    }
\foreach \x in {1,...,\xmax}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    }
\foreach \y in {1,...,\ymax}
    {   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (0,0) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    }
\foreach \y in {\ymin,...,-1}
    {   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (0,0) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    }

% Limitation des tracés dans la zone délimitée par la grille
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);

% Tracés de fonctions
%% Question 2
% d'abord l'orange
\draw[orange, fct, domain=\xmin-1:\xmax] plot (\x+1,{(\x^(1/3))+3});
\node[orange] (h) at (0.6,1.6) {$h(x)$};
%\draw[orange] (0.3,1.6) node {$h$};;
 puis le bleu
\draw[bleu, fct, domain=\xmin-1:\xmax] plot (\x,{-(\x/7)^2 + (10/3)});
\node[bleu] (i) at (-4.4,2.4) {$i(x)$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

You don’t say which PDF converter you are using, but it is more likely to be able to convert this PDF, which uses OpenType fonts and a Unicode mapping table, to a SVG with selectable text that uses the same fonts.

If not, your encoder is falling back to the default font, so look for an option to change it.  You could also have the converter render the letters as line drawings.

Comment: Please, can you demonstrate your solution in MWE  provided by OP?

Comment: Thx! Sooo If a properly understand, the package "sansmath" doesn't add a new font family, but instead copy-paste the police from "\sfdefault"?
... As the author of the package said: "The package’s name could be misconstrued"...
So "sansmath" is not a font family package. it explains a lot...

Comment: I don't know why, but i've got difficulties to understand what the author wrote... while i've got no problem with [schimdt's document](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/schmidt/schmidt.pdf)

Comment: I'm not allow to freely use XeLaTex :/ ... I start to use it because it made it more easy to select specific font (ex: Verdana), but my boss back-pedaled. Do you have any idea why when I convert my PDF to svg, the font family change from TGaventor to default LaTex Font (Times New Roman? / Arial?)

Comment: @Nilcouv If you’re not using `unicode-math`, the PDF would contain an embedded subset of a Type 1 font, which the converter won’t recognize as corresponding to any system font. It also likely will not have a Unicode mapping table. You can check this with `pdffonts`. Therefore, the converter might fall back to the default font.

Comment: @Nilcouv If you can’t use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, look for an option in your PDF-to-SVG converter to select the default font, or even to render as outlines instead of text.

Comment: @Zarko The OP already was aware of how to solve the problem, but wanted to know why the package behaved that way.

Comment: @Davislor, but me not. If this matter :-(

Comment: @Davislor yeah that's the solution a colleague of mine found to solve the problem. thanks for you help.

Comment: @Zarko All right, I added working MWEs.

Comment: @Davislor, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic, since fonts issues at use of the command `\sansmath` is solved by @Davislor answer (+1).

For my exercise: how to draw your diagram with `pgfplots` that use `\sansmath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
% when is used pgflatex
\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{sansmath}

% when is used xelatex
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale = 1.0]
%\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
%\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
%\setmathfont[version=sans]{Fira Math}
%\newcommand\sansmath{\mathversion{sans}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
             width=15cm,height=15cm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
%%%% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/
%%%%            15475/using-ifthenelse-in-pgfmath/15491#15491
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ifthenelsefpu}{3}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#2 + !#1*#3}%
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\sansmath % <==========  
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelsefpu(#1<0,-abs(#1)^(1/3)+3,#1^(1/3)+3)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(\x/7)^2 + (10/3)}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style = {-Stealth, thick, shorten >=-3mm, shorten <=-3mm},
    grid=major,
    axis on top,
    xmin=-7, xmax=3,
    ymin=-3, ymax=7,
    xlabel={$x$},
    x label style={font=\large, xshift=3mm, anchor=west},
    ylabel={$f(x)$},
    y label style={font=\large, yshift=3mm, anchor=south},
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, fill=white},
    samples at = {-7,-6,...,0,0.025,0.05,...,2,3},
            ]
\addplot [blue,   ultra thick]
    {g(x)}     node[pos=0.95,above] {$i(x)$};
\addplot [orange, ultra thick]
    {f(x-1)}    node[pos=0.95,above] {$h(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice the font TEX Gyre Adventor for the labels of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

@Zarko for pgfplots, I solved the problem like this:
[image]

Main.tex

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{parameters.tex}
%\input{preamble.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Variable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Axe x
\newcommand{\xmin}{-0.5}%                  Valeur minimum sur x
\newcommand{\xmax}{11}%                 Valeur maximum sur x
\newcommand{\xlab}{Notes des élèves}%    Titre de l'axe x
\newcommand{\xticks}{0}%                Nombre de graduations en x

%   Axe y
\newcommand{\ymin}{0}%                  Valeur minimum sur y
\newcommand{\ymax}{5}%                  Valeur maximum sur y
\newcommand{\ylab}{Nombre d'élèves}%   Titre de l'axe y
\newcommand{\yticks}{0}%                Nombre de graduation en y

%  Coordonnée des barres
%   (#1, #2) ==> 
%   #1=l'abscisse de la barre ; 
%   #2=L'ordonnée -(/hauteur) de la barre.

\newcommand{\listep}{(0, 0) 
                    (1, 1) 
                    (2, 2)
                    (3, 0)
                    (4, 2)
                    (5, 2)
                    (6, 3)
                    (7, 4)
                    (8, 3)
                    (9, 2)
                    (10, 2)
                    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.15,
    tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sansmath]
\begin{axis}[
            %height=5cm,
            %width=20cm,
            %enlargelimits=0.05,
            %enlarge x limits=false,
            yticklabels={-1,...,5},
            xticklabels={0,...,10}, 
            xtick={0,...,10}, 
            %xticklabel style={anchor=north},
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            xlabel={\xlab},
            ylabel={\ylab},
            xmin=\xmin, xmax=\xmax,
            ymin=\ymin, ymax=\ymax,
            minor x tick num = \xticks,
            minor y tick num = \yticks,
            %area style,
            %xmajorgrids=true,
            %xminorgrids=true
            ymajorgrids=true,
            %yminorgrids=true,
            grid style=line,
            ]
                \addplot+[ybar, mark=no, orange, fill=orange!50!white] plot coordinates {\listep};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Parameters.tex

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PARAMETRES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author{Oscar.education}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{245,128,37}
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{gris}{RGB}{158,158,158}
\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,178,0}
\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{RGB}{190,0,120}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setmainfont{sansmath}
%\setsansfont{sansmath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% OTHER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TIKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Paramètres de l'image

%\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\Verdana}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=1}}      % non-fonctionnel, ne rajoute pas la police verdana à Tikz

\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=1}} 
    % \sansmath pour expressions math. sans empattement (sans serif)
    % \sffamily pour texte normal sans empattement

% Style pour le tracé de fonctions
\tikzset{fct/.style={thick, opacity=0.8, smooth, samples=200}}

% Style pour le remplissage de surfaces
\tikzset{surf/.style={gray!50!white,fill,opacity=0.6}}

% Style pour les points
\newcommand{\sommet}[4]
    {
        \draw[fill=orange] (#1,#2) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[#3] (#1,#2) node {#4};
    }

% Style pour la base inférieure des solides
\tikzset{baseinf/.style={thick, top color=gray!50!black, bottom color=gray!10, middle color=gray, shading=axis, opacity=0.25}}
% Style pour la surface latérale des solides
\tikzset{corps/.style={thick, left color=gray!50!black, right color=gray!50!black, middle color=gray!50, shading=axis, opacity=0.25}}
% Style pour la base supérieure des solides
\tikzset{basesup/.style={thick, top color=gray!90, bottom color=gray!2, middle color=gray!30, shading=axis, opacity=0.25}}
```